How to understand current through a capacitor leads voltage by π/2
We know that when a cosine voltage is applied to a capacitor, it generates the current:
$$I=\frac{dq}{dt}=C\frac{dv}{dt}=C\frac{d}{dt}\cos(\omega t)=-\omega C\sin(\omega t)=C\omega\cos(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2})$$
So we say the current leads the voltage by π/2.
However, in reality, it's the voltage which causes current, how can the current lead the voltage in time? Should we say the voltage leads the current by 3π/2 instead?

You are on a merry-go-round. There are other people also sitting on the horses and carriages there as it goes in circles. Suppose there is someone ahead of you about a quarter-way forward. Are they "leading" you? Or following, but further back behind you? Does the question even matter? Whether it is a voltage or current source, the cause and effect happen together in time. Don't read too much into words. They are for communication to others. Not a description of reality. Nature doesn't care at all about the words we choose to apply. Never did. Never will.


However, in reality, it's the voltage which causes current,

This is your issue. You shouldn't think that either voltage or current is always the cause and the other is always the effect. They're equally important and either one can "cause" the other.
If you have a circuit driven by an ideal voltage source, it's often convenient to think of voltage as cause and current as effect. But in a circuit driven by an ideal current source it's the other way around.
In a circuit with a non-ideal source, Thevenin and Norton tell us that the source can be seen as either a voltage or current source, and that neither choice is "more right" than the other. (The idea of switching back and forth between voltage-first and current-first views of a circuit is called duality)
That said, if we have a capacitor driven by an ideal voltage source, then \$I = C\frac{dV}{dt}\$ tells us the source will have to produce a current signal that leads the voltage by \$\pi/2\$ in order to do its job. It has to do that because it is producing a steeper \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ as the voltage crosses 0 than when it is near its peak or valley.
